# Is there an '-ism' for 'human rights'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, suffixes

> **Capitalism** means a view that gives priority to *capital* and has *capital* as its pivotal notion.
>
> **Nationalism** means a view that gives priority to what is *national* and has *national* as its pivotal notion.
>
> **Racism** means a view or attitude that emphasises people's *race* and has *race* as its pivotal notion.
>
> ______ means a view that gives priority to *rights* and has *human rights* as its pivotal notion.

What can one put in the blank above? **The 'rights' in question is taken in the sense of (moral or legal) entitlement, as in 'one has a right to ...' or 'one's rights are violated', 'human rights', etc.**

So the question is what to call a view that emphasises 'rights' in the above sense, a view that says 'rights' are the most important thing in some debates, a view in which 'rights' are the most central concept.

Is there any term for such a view, approach, or school of thought? If not, what description could be used for it?

Comment: Do 'righteous' or 'pious' work? Does it have to fit the _-ital_ pattern?

Comment: @marcellothearcane Did you read what I said about what sense of 'right' I have in mind here?

Comment: Please be specific in your question. (The previous comment you dismissed is a valid question.) Does the word you're looking for have to fit the same *pattern* as the other examples—or can it be spelled any way at all so long as it has the meaning you're looking for?

Comment: @JasonBassford If I wanted a particular pattern I would mention in the question. And I don't think the examples I gave all have the same pattern. And what is *-ital* pattern in the question you refer to?

Comment: This is confusing. It is unclear to me what you mean by 'right', especially give the previous examples. Do you mean right as in correct, right as in conservative or reactionary, right as in human rights? Also, your characterization of 'X-ism' as 'a view that gives priority to what is' is not really what '-ism' is about.

Comment: Count me as another of those who question the underlying assumptions of the question. That being said, would "moralism" fit your pattern?

Comment: @Learner I never mentioned *-ital*, that was a different comment. But the three existing words you give all end in *-ism*. It's not unreasonable to assume that you want the fourth word to also end in *ism*. But since that's only an assumption, I had to ask.

Comment: @user888379 Moralism does not mean a view that emphasises 'right' in the sense bolded in the question.

Comment: right has no ism associated with it. derecho, direito, droit are law in Spanish, Portuguese and French and often translated incorrectly as right.

Comment: examples are all questionable, so pattern cannot be established.  It’s a political troll.

Comment: @JasonBassford Your referred to that comment which mentioned -ital. I am looking for what to call the view I described in the question. Views are usually called view words ended with -ism, but not always. For example sometimes -theoretic is used, or -based.

Comment: @Mitch  I bolded the part on what sense of 'right' I intended.

Comment: right is not used like that in English at all. And no ism is a view, by the way.

Comment: To reduce confusion (and be more correct), you should say "...gives priority to *rights* and has *rights* as its pivotal notion."

Comment: @Mitch What is with this changes you have made to my question. I didn't mean only 'human rights'. I mean right generally. For example, a view that emphasises on animals right or environmental rights in environmental philosophy is such a view too. Also I am not looking only for an -ism.

Comment: @Learner 1) I don't think it is a significant restriction to say 'human rights' to the exclusion of animals or the environment. 'Human' rights' is just the way you say it. 2) Using 'right' in singular is not idiomatic English (which would explain a lot of the confusion) - one uses the plural refer to the concept. 3) You're not looking for an '-ism'? Al your examples are that and you didn't specify that you'd accept other suffixes or just any abstract noun for the concept. If you can give a good reason for otherwise then please elaborate.

Comment: @Mitch You changed my question into a totally different question. What should I say? There is already some answers to *your* question here. Maybe I should re-write my question as a new question!

Comment: @Mitch The funny thing is that now it is me that get to accept an answer as the right one to *your* question.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikibooks :Ideologies of Government](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Political_Theory/Ideologies_of_Government) which lists the fifteen forms of Political Ideology incorporated into, or postulated of, Governments, the one which is closest, I would say, to your definition of :

> a view that gives priority to right and has right as its pivotal notion.

. .  is **Classical Liberalism.**

Wikibooks classifies this as :

> Including **natural rights** [...] articulated **the rights** of those outside the traditional power structure to freedom from arbitrary rule ...

Comment: Classical liberalism emphasises on freedom, its central concept is freedom. Of course it freedom is seen here as a right on the part of people, but that is somehting else.

Comment: I'm only going by your own definition and the definition given by Wikibooks.

Comment: @Learner, I think you will need to be more clear on what you meant by "right." In rejecting this answer, you say that it is something else. But whose rights, granted by whom? The Declaration establishing the U.S. talks about inalienable rights from the creator, which is very similar to "natural rights" that this this answer is talking about, even without the divine. On the other hand, a King may say that his right to rule, to own land, to make proclamations comes from the divine.  Yet in other cultures, the right to for example private land ownership does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Moralism seems to fit. It is defined as

> The practice of moralizing, especially showing a tendency to make judgments about > others' morality

Comment: Please add a source.

Answer (score 0):

The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia gives this as one possible definition for the [**Individualism**](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/next/century-dictionary/3064/4/individualism).

> Hence—3. That theory of government that favors the non-interference of the state in the affairs of individuals: opposed to *socialism* or *collectivism*
>
> > Socialism and *individualism* are merely two contrary general principles, ideals, or methods, which may be employed to regulate the constitution of economical society. Rae, Contemporary Socialism. p. 290

The ideology of John Locke has sometimes been called individualism. Take this example from Alexander Campbell Fraiser's annotated version of An Essay Concerning by John Loke (1894) states the following on [page xxxiii](https://books.google.com/books?id=XosXAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PR33&pg=PR33#v=onepage&q&f=false) for instance:

> Direct evidence of this is scanty, and the idealising genius and learning of Cudworth had little in common with the 'ideism' and individualism of Locke.

Or this example from Collected Essays Volume 1 Methods and Results by Thomas H. Huxley (Also 1894):

> I have already said that the founder and father of political individualism, as it is held by its more moderate adhereants at the present day, is John Locke; and that his primary assumptions—the state of nature and the contractual basis of society—are the same as those of his predecessor Hobbes, andof his successors Rousseau and Mably.

[Locke](http://www.let.rug.nl/usa/biographies/john-locke/) himself was a renowned 17th politicial philosopher, who is sometimes said to be the forerunner to the ideologoies of the U.S.A's. founding forefathers, and as you might guess from the root word individual, and a proponent of the concept of natural rights, which are those rights that people have independent of any government granting them.

For an example of Locke's own writing to examine what is being described as individualism, take this exceprt from §88 of Two Treatises of Government:

> Man being Born, as has been proved, with a Title to perfect Freedom, and an uncontrouled enjoyment of all the Rights and Privileges of the Law of Nature, equally with any other man, or Number of Men in the World, hath by Nature a Power, not only to preserve his property, that is, his Life, Liberty and Estate, aganst the Injuries and Attempts of other Men; but to judge of, and punish the breaches of that Law in others, and he is perswaded the Offence deserves, even with Death it Self, in Crimes  where the heinousness of the fact, in his Opinion, Requires it. But because no Political Society can be, nor subsist without having it itself the Power to preserve the Property, and in order thereunto punish the Offenses of all those of that society: There, and there only is Political Society, where every one of the Members hath quitted this natural Power, resign'd it up into the hands of the Community in all cases that exclude him not from appealing for Protection to the Law established by it.

Locke, naturally was not an advocate of lawlessness, so he delimited conditions under which the concept of *tacit consent* in [§119'](https://books.google.com/books?id=BHZKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA223#v=onepage&q=inauthor:locke%20tacit%20consent&f=false) to be governed applies, such as choosing to reside with a certain society. However, the point here is that Locke's philosophy prioritized personal rights before governmental power. As such, the terms used to describe his philosophy are of special interest for the intended semantic nuance. However, with that having been said, the [-ism](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/previous/century-dictionary/3195/4/-ism) suffix has relatively little to do with *prioritization* and more to do with doctrinal practices.

Unfortunately, I can not find an example of Locke himself using the word individualism in this way. Insofar as I can tell, it was only applied to his works posthumously.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, people have used **Human Rightsism** or **Human Rights-ism**.

Rightsism in [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rightism):

> 1 : the principles and views of the Right
>
> 2 : advocacy of or adherence to the doctrines of the Right

---

Some real-world examples:

From [Moral Imperatives and Political Realities: response to“principles, politics, and humanitarian action”](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1747-7093.1999.tb00325.x):

> There is no question that **“Human Rightsism”** has become the dominant political ideology of the international new class, and the common currency of UN treaties, academic conferences, and charitable foundation mission statements.

From [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2010/apr/19/human-rights-new-secular-religion):

> This new **"human rights-ism"** accords great value to the United Nations – notwithstanding its inability to enforce its decisions, and its refusal to make practical demands of its members to be democratic or respect the human rights of their citizens.

From [Breaking The Silence: Voices of Moderation: Islam in a Constitutional Democracy](https://books.google.com/books?id=hSSBCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT102&lpg=PT102&dq=rightsism&source=bl&ots=nIkClIrD5P&sig=ACfU3U1BPyv5meQlpQU5DGK7QmydBwAEXw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTmaeq2tvjAhXDIlAKHT-oDJ04ChDoATAEegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=rightsism&f=false)

> This led Najib to retract his statement on **"human rights-ism"**, but he maintained his position in rejecting humanism, secularism and liberalism.

From [Malaysian Politician Zairil Khir Johari's Twitter](https://twitter.com/zairilkj/status/467117298570895360):

> Najib’s **‘human rights-ism’** a bogeyman to cover up human rights abuses [...]